# VBA automation error for regRead

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to automate a project's routine task of filling excel sheet via Excel VBA. One of column in Excel requires latest date of Windows Update. 
I wrote below subroutine to achieve the same.

```
Sub windowsUpdate()
    Dim windowShell
    Dim regValue

    Set WindowShell = CreateObject("WScript.shell")

    regValue = WindowShell.regRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\Results\Install\LastSuccessTime")
    WScript.echo "Updated date is : " & regValue
End Sub
```

With this I am getting either of 2 errors similar to below .When try to execute the same.

> Invalid Root in registry key
>   "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto
>   Update\Results\Install\LastSuccessTime"

**OR**

> Automation Error: Can not find specified path

I am at very initial level of Excel VBA , any guidance for above two errors will be of great help.

Comment: The posted code has syntax errors. Please post actual code, something that you *really* tried.

Answer (score 3):

It means the registry key does not exist.

Use the following functions to check if the key exists and if yes read it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub WindowsUpdate()
    Dim strKey As String
    strKey = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\Results\Install\LastSuccessTime"

    If RegKeyExists(strKey) Then
        MsgBox "Value is: " & RegKeyRead(strKey), vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "Key does not exist.", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub

'read an existing registry key
Function RegKeyRead(i_RegKey As String) As String
    Dim myWS As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    Set myWS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 'access Windows scripting
    RegKeyRead = myWS.RegRead(i_RegKey) 'read key from registry
End Function

'test if a registry key exists
Function RegKeyExists(i_RegKey As String) As Boolean
    Dim myWS As Object

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Set myWS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 'access Windows scripting
    myWS.RegRead i_RegKey 'try to read the registry key
    RegKeyExists = True 'key was found
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    'key was not found
    RegKeyExists = False
End Function
```

Comment: Yes key does not exists if checked from your script. But I can see the value in above location via regedit.

Comment: @MKay re-check the whole registry path if it is the same as in your VBA.